# Traversing Multiple List within Multiple Dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

Ok, I know there are several questions similar to this but not had any luck. What I  have is (2) for loops with a while statement inside the inner for loop and 2 dictionaries with list as values. What I wish to accomplish is get a new key and do some calculations, enter second loop, count the number of items in the second dictionary value list, loop thru those list values using info from first loop to perform some calculations, once all values have been read for that key break back to the first loop get the next key and so on. The number of keys for each dictionary will always be equal. The v length for the seconddict will vary, for instance the first time thru the second for loop, the counterlist[1] value should be 9 but as shown in the results below it's only counting 4 which is the number of values in the first for loop. Actually the second For loop is only counting 4 for each time thru instead of the true length value of v. If I include the key in the second for loop such as for k, v in seconddict.items(), it does count correctly, but then I get the problem where on each entry into the second for loop it starts at the first k and duplicates all my results with each pass thru. Can I get some advice on making this work?

```
def opti(self, firstdict, seconddict):
    self.firstdict=firstdict
    self.seconddict=seconddict
    for key, value in self.firstdict.items():
        print('****NEW KEY AND DO OTHER STUFF****)
        for v in self.seconddict[key]:
            print(---INSDIE SECOND DICT---')
            x=0
            counterlist=[key, len(list(filter(None, v)))]
            while x < couterlist[1]:
                x+=1
                print(x)
                if x >= counterlist[1]:
                    if key in finaldict:
                        print('====SAVE HERE===')
                    else:
                        print('SOMETHING ELSE')
                    break
                else:
                    continue
        break   





 **CURRENT RESULTS:**
    *********************NEW RUN*******************
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  3
    1
    2
    3
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  3
    1
    2
    3
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  3
    1
    2
    3
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  3
    1
    2
    3
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======

   **NEEDED RESULTS:**
    *********************NEW RUN*******************
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  9
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  2
    1
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  5
    1
    2
    3
    4
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
    *********NEW KEY***********  SIZE   4
    RAW DICT SIZE  4
    ------INSIDE RAWDICT---------   COUNTERLIST SIZE  3
    1
    2
    3
    ======SOMETHING ELSE======
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after little more looking, I was using the counterlist that I had been using in another section of code. By changing this to the following I was able to make it work. This might be useful for others using list as key value pairs in dictionaries to count the number of values inside each.

```
length_dict = {key: len(v) for key, v in self.rawdict.items()}
            length_key = length_dict[key]
            counterlist=length_key
```